# How to Select Div within a Div with index in Xpath Syntax?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, xpath

```
<div class="j-C j-C-yj" style="max-height: none; -moz-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 218px; top: 105px; display: none;" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true">
    <div id=":1r" class="j-qn" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="separator"></div>
    <div id=":1u" class="j-qn" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="separator"></div>
</div>
```

so far i am creating xpath to select element with id=":1r" is

"(//div[contains(@class,'j-C') and contains(@class ,'j-C-yj')]/div)[1])"

i had also tried

"(//div[contains(@class,'j-C') and contains(@class ,'j-C-yj')]/div)[1])"

but none is working please help !

P.S : I cannot find element with id as id of the page is created dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "j-C") and contains(@class, "j-C-yj")]')` as another answer already showed you.

#### Another Updates:

As OP kept changing the constraints of the question, here is the full solution does exactly what OP eants.

Sample: I'm using **lxml** to parse your string and do the xpath

```
from lxml import etree

s = '''<div class="j-C j-C-yj" style="max-height: none; -moz-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 218px; top: 105px; display: none;" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true">
    ...:     <div id=":1r" class="j-qn" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="separator"></div>
    ...:     <div id=":1u" class="j-qn" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="separator"></div>
    ...: </div>'''

# I need to wrap your string with <root> element otherwise first div will become the root
tree = etree.fromstring('<root>'+s+'</root>')

# xpath always returns a list, so just loop through the list and the first element is what you want
for node in tree.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "j-C") and contains(@class, "j-C-yj")]'):
    print etree.tostring(node[0])
<div id=":1r" class="j-qn" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="separator"/>
```

Comment: the id changes every time so i can not use id to locate the element

Comment: @SalmanHasni, I've updated my answer to retrieve nodes by **class**.

Comment: Yes the class with remain the same

Comment: @SalmanHasni, so basically you don't really need to check the parent div, just iterate all divs with `j-qn` **class** you will get what you want by then checking the node's id

Comment: there are many other div with class='j-qn' outside the parent div so for that i really need to provide the parent path first

Comment: @SalmanHasni, lol ok. You should have really put all these contraints on OP so people know exactly why and what your expected output is, I will update my answer later on.

Comment: @SalmanHasni, I have again updated the answer. Same approach as your class is the same, but just check the parent div and retrieve the first child node

Comment: I also want to inform u that i have a another div with class='j-C j-C-yj tk-C' does it effect the output ?

Comment: @SalmanHasni, that's getting a bit annoying as the requirements keep changing without clearly explained in OP. I have AGAIN updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a problem in your xpath towards the end. Try this piece of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'j-C') and contains(@class ,'j-C-yj')]/div[1]")
```

Comment: Please provide more of the html code snippet. I am suspecting there are multiple div elements with class "j-C j-C-yj", hence it is not able to detect the concerned element

Comment: i have a another div with class='j-C j-C-yj tk-C' does it effect the output ?

Comment: It definitely will, if this is the parent div and it has multiple elements with class='j-C j-C-yj'. In that case, your code won't be able to click on the specified element. That's why I have asked for a more complete HTML code snippet.